# Call variable from extension with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, controller, apex

This is my controller:

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public myObject__c myObj {get; set;} 
    public String myObjectId;  

    public Boolean one;
    public Boolean two;
    public Boolean three;

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
        myObjectId = standardController.getRecord().id;
    }


    public MyController() {

        String query = 'SELECT id, one__c, two__c, three__c FROM myObject__c WHERE ID = :myObjectId LIMIT 1';

        myObject__c obj = database.query(query);

        one = plan.one__c;
        two = plan.two__c;
        three = plan.three__c;

    }

}
```

I want to pass one of the Boolean values into an alert on this page:

```
<apex:page standardController="StandardController" extensions="MyController">


    <script>

        alert('{!one}')

    </script>


</apex:page>
```

But Im getting the following error in Eclipse when I try to add the alert to me page:

```
Unknown Property: 'StandardController.one'
```

So it's looking in the StandarController for the value, when it should be looking in the extension.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Its probably looking at both. You need a "getter"; one way to provide one is `public Boolean one {get; set;}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Keith C said... you are missing your getters.. the rest of it looks fine. In the correction below, I have added getters and setters

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public myObject__c myObj {get; set;} 
    public String myObjectId;  

    public Boolean one {get;set;}   /* <--- missing this */
    public Boolean two {get;set;}   /* <--- missing this */
    public Boolean three {get;set;} /* <--- missing this */

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
        myObjectId = standardController.getRecord().id;
    }


    public MyController() {

        String query = 'SELECT id, one__c, two__c, three__c FROM myObject__c WHERE ID = :myObjectId LIMIT 1';

        myObject__c obj = database.query(query);

        one = plan.one__c;
        two = plan.two__c;
        three = plan.three__c;

    }

}
```